# How to convert some number as text in Excel into number?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I just ran a Macro and got the below:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Range("B4").Activate
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
End Sub
```

Now couldn't understand the difference between `Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"` and `Selection.NumberFormat = "@"` Can you help me to understand the same?

**I was also trying to convert some number as text in Excel into number. What would be good syntax  to do so?**

Snapshot:

[image: Existing Number format]

**EDIT**

I tried to convert all numbers which is stored as `text` to number by the below,but nothing changed. Please guide if I am wrong:

```
objSheet1.Columns(11).NumberFormat = "0"
```

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**, but nothing changed in the column level. please help me here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Col B
        .Columns(2).NumberFormat = "0.00"

        '~~> Get the last row
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            .Range("B" & i).Formula = .Range("B" & i).Value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Please see my description,where you can see the number,which has left-upper end a green symbol. now If I click on that icon,it let me a chance to change the `Text to Number`. But I want to do the same dynamic. But how could I do so?

Comment: Yes it is running, but coming as `58307132.00`- which should come as `58307132`. How to do so?

Comment: Hint ;) See the line `.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "0.00"` in the code above

Comment: Yes I have seen that, But should I change it to `0` only?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a text stored as a number in a cell to a number, you could try something like this:

```
Sub ConvertTextInCellToNumber(ByVal cellLocation As String)

Dim txt As String
txt = range(cellLocation).text

On Error GoTo Catch

Dim txtAsNumber As Double
txtAsNumber = txt

range(cellLocation).Value = txtAsNumber

Catch:

End Sub
```

Comment: please read my 2nd question! I have some numbers which are in the column as`text` but I want to convert them to `number` in the column level itself. say i have numbers `456676` , `334562` but they are in `text` format, caused to comparisons mismatch!

Comment: Please see the screen shot

Comment: can we do it at column level, instead of doing so cell by cell?